# Django - Abstract Models cannot be instantiated

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, djongo

I created two models `MailGroup` and `Recipient` (shown below). I set Recipient's abstract property to true. When I try to list the MailGroup objects using the `mailGroups = MailGroup.objects.all()`, I'm getting the following error

```
TypeError: Abstract models cannot be instantiated.
```

This is my models.py file:

```
from djongo import models

class Recipient(models.Model):
    recipientName = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = False)
    recipientMailId = models.EmailField(max_length = 255, unique = True, null = False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class MailGroup(models.Model):
    mailGroupName = models.CharField(max_length = 255, unique = True, null = False)
    recipients = models.ArrayField(
        model_container = Recipient
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = False
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from dashboardServer.models import MailGroup

class MailGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MailGroup
        fields = ["id", "mailGroupName", "recipients"]
```

views.py

```
@api_view(["GET", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE"])
def mailGroupsView(request):

    if request.method == "GET":
        mailGroups = MailGroup.objects.all() #throws the error which I mentioned above
        serializer = MailGroupSerializer(mailGroups, many = True)
        return JsonResponse({
            "status": "success",
            "info": "Mail groups fetched successfully",
            "title": "Success",
            "data": serializer.data
        }, status = 200)
```

I'm currently using django version 4.1.9, sqlparse 0.2.4 and djongo 1.3.6

Comment: Can you explain *why* `Receipt` is `abstract = True`?

Answer (score 0):

NOTE - You can not create an object of **`Recipient`** model because it is an abstract model

-You need to inherit **`Recipient`** model in **`MailGroup`** model

```
class Recipient(models.Model):
    recipientName = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = False)
    recipientMailId = models.EmailField(max_length = 255, unique = True, null = False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class MailGroup(Recipient):
    mailGroupName = models.CharField(max_length = 255, unique = True, null = False)
    recipients = models.ArrayField(
        model_container = Recipient
    )
```

after inherit **`Recipient`** in **`MailGroup`** you can use **`(recipientName,recipientMailId)`** fields via object of **`Recipient`** model

for more info open link [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

Comment: when did I create an object of recipient?

Comment: @DanielVanum: when you have a `model_container=...` that model should be concrete. But using an array is usually a very (very) bad idea in a relational database.